# How to have Azure App Service Tomcat to forward all 80/443 traffic to JBoss running on the same App Service

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, jboss, b2b

First of all, my Azure subscription is through a Cloud Service Provider, so I don't have access to certain features (i.e. cannot install a marketplace tomcat, only the native one; with the native Tomcat I do not have access to server.xml, which I need for some traffic rerouting solutions - modifying Connectors).

The basic need is to have IBM's B2B Client app running and sending files back and forth.  It comes with its own JBoss, and all you do is put the app in a directory on Azure App Service and run the executable.  This is already not a problem, and I have it starting with the app service using a WebJob.

Problem: 
App Service only has two inbound ports open - 80 and 443, and they are both being used by Tomcat.

So I need to either:

1) Disable Tomcat, and only have JBoss running and listening on those ports without conflicts;

or

2) Have native Tomcat forward traffic to JBoss.

How can I do either of those in this environment, and are there better solutions for this problem?

Comment: If you're asking about additional ports, that's not possible with web apps: only 80 and 443 are supported.

Comment: How can I get Tomcat to let JBoss use those ports?  I am not even using the Tomcat, I only have it because it comes with the App Service, and I don't know how to get rid of it.  All I want is to have this third-party JBoss app run on an App Service and use ports 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

According to the subsection `Network endpoint listening` of the wiki page [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening) of Kudu for Azure App Services, you couldn't use the other ports on Azure App Service besides `80` & `443` to access the application server from the internet. So if you can't create a [JBoss AS instance from Azure Marketplace](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bitnami/jbossas/), per my experience, I think the only way is that creating an Azure VM instance to install a JBoss AS instance to deploy your specified Java Application.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.